# Do Keyboard Shortcuts (Ctrl + F1) Without Fn Key

Tags: windows-10, laptop, keyboard-shortcuts, function-keys

On my old Windows laptop, there were action keys to change the brightness, volume, etc. These are the same keys for using function keys (<kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>F3</kbd>, etc). When pressing one of these keys, it would do the action, and pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd> would use the function keys. However, when doing a keyboard shortcut (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>) I would not need to press Fn.

All this is to say, on my new laptop (also Windows, but a different brand) , I cannot do keyboard shortcuts such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> without also using the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key. I know about turning off Action Keys mode in the BIOS, but I still want to be able to use them on my old laptop. Is this possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the Function Keys to say what the top row of keys is (that is, switch what Fn does for the top row of keys) in the BIOS, but you cannot (in any laptop I have seen) switch in BIOS what (say) <kbd>F1</kbd> and <kbd>F2</kbd> do (that is, you cannot switch them).

Almost all laptops however can control Sound and Brightness with some Function key arrangement.

You need to look at your Laptop Quick Start guide to see what that is.